# Can I use TLP and CPUFreq at the same time?

Tags: 14.04, cpufreq, tlp

I just started using ubuntu 14.04 recently. I read that it's good to have CPUFreq or TLP. I was wondering if it would be okay to have both.
Would it cause any problems with the computer performance if I have both running?

Answer (score 2):

CPUfreq is actually built-in with the Linux kernel. This is the tool that manages CPU frequency. You may be thinking of `indicator-cpufreq`, which adds a function to the panel allowing the user to easily control CPUfreq settings. This is a simple way to change between frequencies or governors. The `cpufrequtils` package is a dependency of `indicator-cpufreq`, but is not needed by TLP.

TLP is an optional program that can be installed. It manages many different settings for power consumption. CPU frequency is one of these that it can manage, and it uses CPUfreq in the kernel to do this.

So you already have CPUfreq by default. TLP can help managing power settings, and CPUfreq is one of the many tools it can control. The CPUfreq indicator is another option for managing CPUfreq.

See this explanation for more info about this.

[Is there a power saving application similar to Jupiter?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/285434/is-there-a-power-saving-application-similar-to-jupiter)

Answer (score 2):

You don't need both. TLP can itself handle the cpu's settings. Take a look at the [settings docs](http://linrunner.de/en/tlp/docs/tlp-configuration.html#scaling).

@Nattgew: TLP doesn't need or use cpufrequtils.

Comment: This is the correct answer. In fact, in the current versions cpufreqd will override TLP settings like the scaling governor or min/max frequencies, based on its own configuration; so it's not a good idea to run both, and TLP should be ideal choice as it is a lot more powerful/capable.